# Windows 8.1 shutdown/restart unsuccessful Leovo y560

Tags: windows-8.1, shutdown, reboot, lenovo-laptop

My lenovo y560 is not shutting down. Blue screen follows and then system restart occurs with ERROR: *DRIVER_POWERSTATE_FAILURE*. I refreshed my PC, turned off `Hybrid Sleep` and `Fast Shutdown` but problem reccurs. Thanks in advance.

C:\Windows\Minidump archived, [download here](http://www.swghosh.tk/?url=42) or [mirror](http://1drv.ms/1tc9IRu)

Comment: copy the folder C:\windows\Minidump to the desktop, zip the folder, upload the zip to a cloud service and post a link here.

Comment: zip file uploaded @http://files.swghosh.tk/mindump.zip

Comment: ok, I posted an answer.

Comment: have you tried the driver update? Is the issue fixed now?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I [checked the dumps with Windbg](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) and it looks like the AMD graphic card driver `atikmpag.sys` for your ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5730 causes the issue:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffe00001f63060, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff80383306b90, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffe00007e75590, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5215f837

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff80000579000 pci

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck
nt!PopIrpWatchdog
nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList
nt!KiExpireTimerTable
nt!KiTimerExpiration
nt!KiRetireDpcList
nt!KxRetireDpcList
nt!KiDispatchInterruptContinue


FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_POWER_DOWN_atikmpag_IMAGE_pci.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_power_down_atikmpag_image_pci.sys


  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffe000043f3040 *** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for atikmpag.sys

  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_68C0&SUBSYS_392717AA&REV_00\4&36714c63&0&0018"
  ServiceName is "amdkmdap"

    Loaded symbol image file: atikmpag.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\atikmpag.sys
    Image name: atikmpag.sys
    Timestamp:        Sat Jul 05 03:26:52 2014
```

First, update your Windows 8.1, to the latest Update Rollup level from december 2014, you still use a patch level from 2013 (9600.16404.amd64fre.winblue_gdr.**130913**-2141), next update the [AMD GPU driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/mobile?os=Windows%208.1%20-%2064) and look if this fixes it.